# Creating a new collection inside existing collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am currently trying to put a backbone model inside an already existing model. I was wondering if this is even possible.

```
var rf = this.collection.create(attrs, options);
Model.set(table, rf);
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your trying to do, but you can certainly have one of the properties of your model be another model or collection. You can *instantiate* it in your [initialize](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) method (in fact if you look at the example in the documentation you'll see that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you trying to do is "Nested Models & Collections". Backbone already has preferable [approach](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-nested). The common idea consist in storing of nested model directly in the instance of another model instead attributes.

So, you could create child model first and then pass it to parent model through `options` like the following:

```
var rf = this.collection.create(attrs, options);

var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function(attributes, options) {
    _.isObject(options) || (options = {});

    if (options.child) {
        this.child = new options.child;
    }        
  }
});

var model = new Model({}, {child: rf});
```

If you want to get a fully supported tree-like Backbone models you could try to use one of the following [plugins](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/Extensions%2C-Plugins%2C-Resources#model).

Hope this helps!